# Change the format of the text in a cell to striketrough

Tags: google-apps-script

Below is the code which would do some basic conditional formatting of a range of cells. This code sets the background color to red. Now I want to change the text format to <s>Striketrough</s>. But as the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text) says, `setStrikethrough` is a function in the `class Text`. Now how could I implement this in the example below?

Here is my scenario:

```
function onEdit() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Actiepunten');
  var rows = sheet.getRange('a1:j');
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
    for (var x in values[i]){
      if (values[i][x] == 'Done' || values[i][x] == 'done'){
        var n = i + 1;
        var Range = sheet.getRange('a'+n+':f'+n).setBackgroundColor('red');

     }
   } 
 }
 };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the spreadsheet app documentation.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setFontLine(String)

.setFontLine("line-through");